# gui tkinter python3 not working always stopping

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

my code for the ***tkinter*** gui is-

this code shows that my gui is ***not responding***

im making a voice assitant this code i refereed from another website and tried to run in my spyder or jupyter but couldnt run it as it was showing not responding
it didnt take the voice as input at all

I read some stack but im not sure if it would help so want some help regarding the code whats wrong

I read some post multi threading would work should i try that?

```
from tkinter import*
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import random
import time
from tkinter import messagebox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
class Window(Frame):
    #defining our main window
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        master.title("DREAM")
        A=Label(master,text="try saying *what can you do*")
        A.pack(side="top")
        Button(master,text="listen",width=100,relief="groove",command=self.Processo_r).pack(side="bottom")
    def Processo_r(self):
        speech=str(self.speech_recog())

        if speech=="What can you do":
            self.functions()  
    def speak(self,output):
        #initiating the speech engine
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        #speaking the desired output 
        engine.say(output)
        engine.runAndWait()
    def functions(self):
        self.speak("here is a list of what i can do")
        messagebox.showinfo("DREAM functions", "1.Try saying 'Hi','Hello'" +
                            "\n2.Try asking 'What day is this?'" +
                            "\n3.Try asking 'What month is it?'" +
                            "\n4.Try asking 'What time is it?'" +
                            "\n5.You search in google by saying...'Search (or) Google <anything>'" +
                            "\n6.Play youtube by saying'YouTube... <video_name>'" +
                            "\n7.Search in Wikipedia by saying...'wikipedia...<anything>'" +
                            "\n8.To close say 'Bye' or 'Sleep' or 'See you later'")

    def speech_recog(self):
        #recognizer class
        r=sr.Recognizer()
        #Specifing the microphone to be activated
        mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

        #listening to the user 
        with mic as s:
            audio = r.listen(s, timeout=5)
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(s)

        #Converting the audio to text  
        try:
            speech = r.recognize_google(audio)
            return speech

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            #calling the text to speech function
            self.speak("please try again,couldnt identify")

        
        except sr.WaitTimeoutError as e:
            self.speak("please try again") 
    
    
root=Tk()
#instance of the class  
app=Window(root)
root.geometry("300x50")
#Runs the application until we close
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you inherit from `tkinter.Frame` and never use it?

Comment: Also `r.listen(s, timeout=5)` is blocking the code execution for 5 sec. This means that tkinter can't update itself and that is why your window hangs. Try moving the speech detection in another thread.